# Optimal Leon Bottou Learning-rate

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

**According to Leon Bottou on page 10 and page 11, he mentions :**

> Use learning rates of the form $γ_t = γ_0 (1 + γ_0λt)^{−1}$

Im trying to implement it for my neural network but im having t**rouble understanding the variables**...

**I think i understood a few but im still confused :**

$y_t$ = New Learning Rate

$y_0$ = Initial Learning Rate

$λ$ = L2 regularization ? Is this a pre-fixed value ?

$t$ = ? The current epoch on the training Iteration ?

**Reference**

Bottou, Léon. "Stochastic gradient descent tricks." In Neural networks: Tricks of the trade, pp. 421-436. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2012.
http://cilvr.cs.nyu.edu/diglib/lsml/bottou-sgd-tricks-2012.pdf ; https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13393602912095771108&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22

Answer (score 1):

This [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1627052984) mentions this in page 61. The author interprets this as:

1. $t$ is the $t$th training example, and
2. $\lambda$ is an additional hyperparameter